# How to access rotation data for mesh babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

[image]

That was obtained by

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("",'', "ship.babylon", scene, function(newMeshes){

ship = newMeshes;
}

console.log(ship[0])
```

Question: How do I get the Y value Under rotationQuaternion

Answer (score 0):

Hello simply call ship[0].rotationQuaternion
Just make sure there is a rotationQuaternion as rotation can also be expressed using Euler angles with .rotation which is a vector3